# Best practices to get Base-URL and Absolute-Path

Tags: php

I know there a some questions about the subject, but they all contain different answers. I am wondering what is most efficient way to get the base url and absolute path as of 5.4 +

Absolute path: Using magic constant

```
define('ROOT', __DIR__); //C:\wamp\www
```

Alternatively write the path yourself once

```
define('ROOT', 'C:\wamp\www');
```

Final use:

```
require ROOT . '/blabla/test.php';
```

How should I receive the absolute path otherwise? What option would be most efficient unless there aren't any better method?

About the base url, I'm not quite sure how to generate the url.

Comment: Those parts of the application that need the value should get it injected. Most likely as a `SplFileInfo` object (or an abstracted interface that covers different concrete implementations) so that you can actually keep it flexible. I would consider that best practice. Because you normally don't need to care how the value is being obtained but how it is used. Also you are mixing terms here, what you talk about is not the base URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I generally go about this.
Bear in mind I use apache locally (Windows) which can handle '/' directory separators, not sure about IIS etc.

Folder structure:

```
C:/wamp/www/somefolder
    /index.php
    /core
        /database.php
        /config
            /database.php
```

index.php:

```
// ROOT will be C:/wamp/www/somefolder
define('ROOT', str_replace('\\', '/', dirname(__FILE__)));
define('CORE', ROOT . '/core');
define('CONFIG', CORE . '/config');
require(CORE . '/database.php');
```

/somefolder/core/database.php:

```
require(CONFIG . '/database.php');
```

So basically I use `dirname(__FILE__)` in the index.php file. It always works for me and is my trusted way to get the correct path to the root directory.